# Is there a more efficient / faster way to query the DB for results

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering if there is a better way to retrieve these results:

```
@product_ids_by_collection = Product.where(collection_id: collection_id).pluck(:id)
@component_ids = ProductComponent.where(product_id: @product_ids_by_collection).pluck(:component_id).uniq
@category_ids = Component.where(id: @component_ids).pluck(:category_id).uniq
return Category.find(@category_ids)
```

In the above, I'm starting at the `product` level and working my way back to figure out what `categories` the `collection` belongs to. The hierarchy looks like:

- Category > Component > Product
- Collection > Product

I've omitted the Models to cut down on the visual clutter, but please let me know if further info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the associations correctly, this would simply be:

```
Category.joins(:components => :products).
         where(:products => {:collection_id => collection_id})
```